# Gradle dependencies: Parenthesis vs single/double quotes only

Tags: android, gradle

When naming dependencies in the Cradle-file: What's the difference between putting the string within parenthesis or just quotes alone.

For example:
`implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:2.2.2")`

Versus:
`implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.3'`

I see both forms all the time. **When do I use which?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both notation are available and are equivalent , in the Groovy DSL: see explanation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:optional_parentheses_on_method_calls)

Reference to this feature in Groovy specifications: https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses

In Koltin DSL, only the *method call* version (with parenthesis) is available.

"When do I use which? " : personally I prefer using the version with parenthesis , making it simpler to migrate to Kotlin DSL later : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_groovy_to_kotlin_dsl.html#prepare_your_groovy_scripts